# A less derogatory word than "cheap"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Can you help me to identify the **right word** that can match with the following description for a product:

> basic and budget-friendly but not holding the negative context of
>   "cheap."

I have come up with many options: simple, basic, traditional, etc. but the "right" word has not come to mind yet.

Any helpers? I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: How ’bout ***value***?

Comment: **economical** for "cheap", **regular** for "basic/standard".

Comment: *cost-effective*?

Comment: Requests for *name* suggestions are strictly off-topic. Before closure or deletion, it might be a good idea to edit your question. Ask simply for synonyms.  Having said that, I'm going to pour myself a glass of Waitr*se **Essentials** grapefruit juice.

Comment: @User_kk I have edited the post to comply with ELL guidelines. Check if it is okay by you else I can reverse the changes.

Comment: What about **affordable** for budget-friendly? And **classic** for traditional?

Comment: I was not aware of the name suggestion topic being off-limits. I was just searching for words and came upon this helpful site, so I wanted to use it as well. Deleting the post soon. Sorry for any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **essential** for basic and **affordable** for budget-friendly.

From the definition found in Merriam-Webster website

Source--[Essential](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essential)

[Affordable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affordable)

Comment: Can you offer any definitions, sources or examples to support your suggestions?

Comment: @JHCL-------definition from Merriam-Webster----- used to describe a product that is not expensive to own and use ----, I am attaching the link here---http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/economical

Comment: You posted the dictionary link for *economical*, which you never suggested in your answer. (?)

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, corrected now....@Mari-LouA

Comment: You still have the dictionary entry for *economical*, but your answers are: *essential*, and *affordable*. Give the definition for these two terms.

Comment: [**essential**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essential) : extremely important and necessary and [**affordable**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affordable): *to be able to pay for (something)*

Comment: Sorry corrected now @Mari-LouA

Answer (score 2):

Economical can mean budget-friendly.

Depending on the context, 'entry level' can mean basic; such as an entry level model for cars.  You could also try 'standard', which doesn't imply cheap in my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word but nevertheless a compound noun, so you can join the two words with the hyphen **best-buy**.
Oxford Dictionaries say

> **[best buy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/best-buy?q=best%20buy)**
>   An item or product which gives the best value for money out of all its competitors.
>
> e.g. *Their recommendation of which shop has the best buy must then be reviewed by the 23 member Ethics Committee to make sure that the shop doesn't sell alcohol or Lottery tickets.*